# Embed Shutterfly album on a website

Tags: php, api, embed, image-gallery, atom-feed

I'm currently trying to work out if/how it might be possible to embed a Shutterfly album (or multiple albums actually) into a website.

I found a couple of API-related FAQs but wasn't entirely sure how to use the information, or if it was possible, to build a gallery page on an external website using the Atom feed from Shutterfly. My PHP skills are pretty basic!

http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_Folder.sfly
http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_Album.sfly

I assume that I can take the Atom feed, use PHP to process and output a feed of thumbnails and links to the full images? Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shutterfly has a built-in "embed code" feature to do this.  When viewing the album on shutterfly.com, move your cursor over the lower right corner of the page where it says "Post to:" with icons for Facebook and Blogger.  You should see a pop up menu that lists "Facebook", "Blogger", and "**Get embed code**".  Choose "**Get embed code**", copy the code, and paste it into your website.